# Directory is not opening with cd command

Tags: linux, cd-command

I have a directory in Desktop named Project. I tried opening it using the `cd` command but it is not opening. What's the reason?

Check the screenshot. The directory has all the required permissions.

I tried with the root user also, but facing the same problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you do your screenshot with Alt+PrintScreen. It's not visible this way, forcing me to open it in a new Window. Nice background BTW.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks to me like the Project directory has a space at the start of it, so try:

```
cd " Project"
```

If it's something other than a space (say a tab) then

```
cd *Project
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 13):

There is a white space before Project.

Try this:

```
cd \ Project
```

or

```
cd ' Project'
```

or

```
cd " Project"
```

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be an extra space, try:

```
$ cd " Project"
```

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the directory starts with a space. Try `cd \ Project`

Answer (score 0):

Am I the only one who thinks the OP's screen snapshot is a bit strange?

"ls -ll" should sort by filename. If the "Project" file began with some invisible character than looks like a space, why does it sort between "perl" and "Screenshot.png"?

If I go into any directory and do "mkdir ' Project'", then "ls -ll" sorts it at the top of the list.

This looks like a listing produced by "ls -lt".